# Having a query "pick" the earliest date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that has two date fields (reject date and accept date). They both have the criteria set to pick the records that are between a certain date. Is there a way that I can make it so it only looks at the earliest date?

For example, if I enter the date range as 12/1 - 12/31, it will give me a record that has a rejection date of 12/20 and an acceptance date of 1/5. But I would want that one excluded. The only records I would want to be included are those that have both dates in the given range, or one date in the given range with the other date blank (because it is possible to have a rejection date with no acceptance date. It is also possible to have a rejection date but later have an acceptance date after this issues get fixed).

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The search condition would be something like: rejectDate between date1 and date2 OR acceptDate between date1 and date2 OR (rejectDate between date1 and date2 and acceptDate is NULL) OR (acceptDate between date1 and date2 and rejectDate is NULL)

Comment: Why does it give a rejection date of 12/20 and acceptance of 1/5?  Why isn't it being excluded?  If you give some sample data, the desired results and the SQL you're using at the moment someone might be able to figure that out... or you may get a mind reader answering the question, in which case carry on.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should select your desired results (replace * with your desired fields)

```
 select
 *
 from TableName

 where 

    (RejectDate between @Date1 and @Date2
        and AcceptDate between @Date1 and @Date2)
 or
    (RejectDate between @Date1 and @Date2 
        and AcceptDate is null)
 or
    (AcceptDate between @Date1 and @Date2 
        and RejectDate is null)
```